# How to get json using .getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an endpoint https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops?symbols=aapl but when I try to use .getjson with that url I get a 404 error. In the api documentation it mentions that it may be a jsonp request and if so how do I get .getjson to be able to read this call. Thank you in advance.

The code I have tried is...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
  $.getJSON('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/tsla', function(data) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id;
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in CORS we trust. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The URL in your script doesn't match your description's URL. `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops?symbols=aapl`

Comment: I don't think you need `JSON.parse(data);` .. getJSON results in parsed JSON already - if you use the link in the text of your question, it's OK, even has CORS headers ... not sure why you are using a different link in the code - which is invalid

Comment: I realized my mistake. Fortunately I found my mistake which was forgetting to change the json value. Thank you for helping out. Also note. this API has been shut down as of yesterday so its hard to test these endpoints now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using doesn't match your description's URL, and the URL actually returns a 404.

Using your description's URL works, however `getJSON` parses the data so we don't need to do `JSON.parse(data);`.

Finally, your data doesn't actually have a `id` attribute so that will return undefined.

I have changed it to `symbol` which returns AAPL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
  $.getJSON('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops?symbols=aapl', function(data) {
       var obj = data[0];
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.symbol;
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was helpful. Haven't worked with javascript in a while and this helped me remember my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The API or remote resource must set the header. You can try

```
function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');
}
```